# VSCode Python + OneNote

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Я использую VSCODE и для сохранения своих наработок MS OneNote
Я копирую код в OneNote все нормально.
Но когда я копирую весь код обратно в VSCode из OneNote, все пробелы там заменены на Неразделяемые пробелы.

```
&nbsp
```

Из за этого код на питоне не компилится пока я не заменю все на нормальные пробелы.

В VSCODE есть расширение которое показывает эти пробелы. Их можно убрать ручками. Но это долго.
Так же есть пару расширений которые убирают эти пробелы. Но работают неккоректно. Они портят форматирование текста. Либо вообще тупо ставят код в 1 строчку.
Разучить OneNote их не вставлять. Не вариант тоже. Ничего подобного в настройках OneNot Не нашел.
Собственно вопрос. Как в VSCode заменить эти пробелы на нормальные? 
Перерыл инет так ничего нормального не нашел.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

нашел плагин нормально работающий
Fix Irregular Whitespace 
Инсталлируется из VSCODE. Корректно удаляет Whitespace